# how does python operator overloading works

Tags: python, pandas, operator-overloading

I can understand that some langurage allows user to do some operator overloading. I know this in C++ area first.  But c++ also has some restrictions on operator overloading and I think that's reasonable.

but when I come to python pandams library.  I'm start to confused.

Take a look at my code at [nbviewer.jupyter.org](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jvns/pandas-cookbook/blob/v0.1/cookbook/Chapter%203%20-%20Which%20borough%20has%20the%20most%20noise%20complaints%3F%20%28or%2C%20more%20selecting%20data%29.ipynb)

```
complaints['Complaint Type'] == "Noise - Street/Sidewalk"
```

**doesn't return a True or False.**

This is crazy to me.  Does anyone can help me to understand this?

1. in Python,  can we overloading operator == so that it doesn't return a boolean?
2. If it is true for question 1,  how can I wrote a simple code to demo this?

Some relevant results copied from the link:

```
>>> complaints['Complaint Type'] == "Noise - Street/Sidewalk"

0      True
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
...

111063    False
111064    False
111065    False
111066     True
111067    False
111068    False
Name: Complaint Type, Length: 111069, dtype: bool
```

Comment: You're comparing a scalar against an array so the return type is an array of booleans what are you expecting here?

Comment: I'd wager a simple search for python operator overloading would produce multiple duplicate results.

Comment: This has nothing to do with overloading, this is what numpy/pandas refer to as broadcasting (as @EdChum is alluding to).  If you compare a pandas column (arrray) to a scalar, you get an array of booleans (as you show in the link).  Not sure what else you would want or expect in this context?  Here's a link on broadcasting that may help:  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#matching-broadcasting-behavior

Comment: btw, much better to include relevant plain text pasted from the link if possible (I added what I thought was most relevant from the link into the body of the question)

Comment: Also, you're generally better off using pandas string functions rather than `==` to do what your trying to do:  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#testing-for-strings-that-match-or-contain-a-pattern

Comment: This isn't really any crazier than C++ allowing you to overload `,`, and it's way more useful.

Comment: @EdChum,  Usually compare in Python return True or False.   I know Pandas uses some technology which changed that behavior.  I just want to know what technology it is.    Simply  Both [1, 2] == [2, 2] and [1, 2] == 1 return False.  This is the thing I can understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overload operators if you create your own classes and add a `__eq__` method to them.

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __eq__(self, other):
        # compare self with other, return whatever you need
```

This will be invoked whenever you compare your type with `self == other`. It is considered very normal to return a boolean from this function in python, so you might want to have a think about returning anything else if you want your code to make sense to other developers.

See the docs for python 2 on this [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__)

Comment: Alternatively, one can implement the \_\_eq\_\_ method.

Comment: `__cmp__` is expected to return negative integer, 0 or positive integer, of which False and True happen to fulfill 0 and 1.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, eq is the correct operator to overload here - I'll change my answer to reflect that. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks @srowland,  I thought Python also has some restriction on __eq__ that it has to return True or False, but the fact is there is no such restriction.